# Drupal 7.87 MultiSelect issue

Tags: drupal, multi-select

I encountered a weird issue regarding multiselect component. It used to worked ok when Drupal version is 7.67. It stopped working after we upgrade Drupal to 7.87. The issue is the selected options box always show everything (the same as available options box) and with the selected options highlighted instead of only show the real selected options. Please check the following attached screenshot. I expected to only see the highlighted item in the "Selected Options" box.

[image]

Also the "+" and "-" buttons don't work at all.

Any idea what's the root cause of the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

---

OK, finally be able to resolve the issue temporarily. I said "temporarily" here is because I still don't know how to fix it properly.

What I did was:

1. login to Drupal
2. On admin menu, click Configuration -> Development -> jQuery Update
3. Pick any version lower than 3, (I picked 2.2) as "Default jQuery version"
4. On jQuery Migrate tab, check "Enable jQuery Migrate Plugin" checkbox
5. Save the configuration and refresh the content page

It is more like a jQuery compatibility issue to me. Anybody know how to solve this kind of issue in Drupal properly?

Thanks